# Why I cannot import JsonFormat from package com.google.protobuf.util?

Tags: gradle, google-cloud-platform, protocol-buffers, google-cloud-pubsub

Currently, I'm working on google cloud (google pub/sub). I've used java client. But I cannot import JsonFormat class from package com.google.protobuf.util. I'm using intelliJ idea, I have tried invalidate cache and restart the idea. What am I missing?

- My `build.gradle`

```
    // google cloud
    implementation platform('com.google.cloud:libraries-bom:22.0.0')

    implementation 'com.google.cloud:google-cloud-pubsub'
```

- [image: the artifact had been imported]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In latest versions of google cloud bom the package com.google.cloud.protobuf:protobuf-util is used with runtime scope, so it's not available during compilation. Not sure why they changed it...
Adding manually the dependency with compile scope (maven) or implementation (gradle) should help.

Source:
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.cloud/google-cloud-pubsub/1.114.7